# Beam of electromagnetic wave, with radius of 3cm or less

Tags: visible-light, laser, home-experiment, frequency

I need to create a beam of electromagnetic wave, with radius of 3cm or less, for distance about few meters. What is the minimum frequency (maximum wavelength) that it is really possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about propagation through free space, the beam will be diffracted by the aperture you pass it through (3cm in this case) and that will cause the beam to diverge. The far field angular divergence, $\theta$, is approximately given by the equation for the [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk):

$$ \sin\theta \approx 1.22 \frac{\lambda}{d} \tag{1} $$

where $d$ is the diameter of the aperture (3cm) and $\lambda$ is the wavelength you're using. So you just need to decide what angular divergence is acceptable and plug it into equation (1).

Comment: Probably should mention this is limited to free-space EM propagation.  I think coax or waveguides may be different.